# How to I make the X and Y position of an object in unity refer to the top left of the object, instead of the center?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[the image of the object, with the x and y coordinates referring to the middle of the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y41qd.png)

I'm kind of a noob at unity, but I'm pretty sure I've done this before. Is there a way to change the position of the blue circle to the top left of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If That white box is a Sprite, then just click the sprite filed to open it in inspector.  And Click [Sprite Editor] button in the middle of inspector. There you can just drag blue circle (the center of that sprite). And then press [Apply] button in inspector.

If that white box is a GUI Image ( I think probably not.) , then you need too do some scripting for it. ( Just Re-Arrange it whit modified center with code )